# How do I loop through all responses from API and pass them to Google Sheet using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code that gets project ID from google sheet if they meet a criteria (between two dates) and  uses it for an API to get the users in the project. After, **getTeam** function append the response (Team) to a sheet. My challenge is that I am not able to get all the users appended to the sheet in the **getTeam** function. I did not structure well my loops in **readDates**  I will help in structuring the code to get all the users to a sheet.

```
function readDates() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    var range1 = sheet.getRange("C2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var searchString = "Project";
    var ahead = nextweek()
    var behind = lastweek()
    var team_array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        if (range1[i][0] >= behind && range1[i][0] <= ahead) {


                var lastRow = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 1, 1, 8).getValues();
                var dateval = lastRow[0][2]
                var data = {

                    'project_id': lastRow[0][3] // There are 6 projects ID meeting criteria, each project has 7 users

                };


                var options = {
                    method: 'get',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
                    }
                };

                var url = tknurl + Endpoint + data.project_id + '/users?auth=' + token
                var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
                var team = JSON.parse(response);
                var content = team.data;
                team_array.push(content);
            }

        }
   return(content) 
    }
```

**getTeam** function. Where I am only getting users for one project, instead of all 6 projects

```
function getTeam() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Team');
var Pro_data = readDates()

for (var j = 0; j < Pro_data.length; j++) {

ss.getRange(2 + j, 1).setValue(Pro_data[j].id);
ss.getRange(2 + j, 2).setValue(Pro_data[j].first_name);
ss.getRange(2 + j, 3).setValue(Pro_data[j].last_name);
ss.getRange(2 + j, 4).setValue(Pro_data[j].display_name);
ss.getRange(2 + j, 5).setValue(Pro_data[j].email);
ss.getRange(2 + j, 6).setValue(Pro_data[j].user_type_id);
ss.getRange(2 + j, 7).setValue(Pro_data[j].role);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### The [return](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp) statement finishes the execution of a function and exits it

- You use `return(content)` inside the `for` loop
- As a consequence the function will be exited after the first iteration
- Instead, you should create an array to which you append within each iteration the data for each project
- Return the array containing all data after the exiting the `for` loop.

**Sample:**

```
  ...
  var myArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < range1.length; i++) {
    ...
    var content = team.data;
    myArray.push(content);
    ...    
  }
  return content; 
  ...
```

**Side note:**

You can replace the nested if statement

```
if (range1[i][0] >= behind) {
  if (range1[i][0] <= ahead) {
    ...
  }
}
```

through a combined one:

```
if (range1[i][0] >= behind && range1[i][0] <= ahead) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for looking at the code. I have edited my code in the question as per the your suggestion and as much as I now get more users on the sheet, some are still left out. What could be the problem?

Comment: It is hard to say without knowing your data. I recommend you to implement logs, e.g. log `url` and `content` during each iteration and then `Pro_data` - this will help you to see where user data gets lost. Small note: If you modify your question, according to stackoverflow rules your should edit your initial post, rather than posting the update as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have just noticed that I get all the data to the sheet, only that on each subsequent loop, the previous data is overwritten instead of starting from a new row. I apologise for the bother, just getting started with JavaScript. Here is the link to my query, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656367/how-do-i-avoid-overwritting-a-row-in-google-sheet-while-seting-values-from-api-r

Answer (score 1):

You are returning only the first result in readDates function. Your return instruction is inside the loop, you need to aggregate all the results somewhere, you can use an array before executing the return.

```
var contents = [];
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
     ...
     contents.push(content);
     } //close if2
   } //close if1
}//close for
return contents;
```

Comment: thanks for looking at the code. I have edited my code in the question as per the your suggestion and as much as I now get more users on the sheet, some are still left out. What could be the problem?

Comment: Your  for is looping using a variable that is not in the block the name is range and the ifs are using range1