# How do I avoid overwritting a row in google sheet while seting values from API response

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a JavaScript code that gets response from API and sets the values on google spreadsheet.

The data that I get are users on a project that I need recorded to a sheet in spreadsheet.

The only challenge that I need help is avoiding overwriting  existing sheet data on subsequent loop, how can I handle this ?

This first part gets project codes and uses it to make API call where the teams on all the projects are contained in a response.

```
function readDates() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range1 = sheet.getRange("C2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var searchString = "Project";
    var ahead = nextweek()
    var behind = lastweek()
    var team_array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < range1.length; i++) {
        if (range1[i][0] >= behind && range1[i][0] <= ahead) {

            var lastRow = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 1, 1, 8).getValues();
            var dateval = lastRow[0][2]
            var data = {

                'project_id': lastRow[0][3] 
        };


        var options = {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + AUTH
            }
        };

        var url = tknurlL + Endpoint + data.project_id + '/users?auth=' + AUTH 
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
        var team = JSON.parse(response);
        var content = team.data;
        team_array.push(content);           

       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Team');
        const lr = sheet.getLastRow();

        for (var j = 0; j < content.length; j++) {

            ss.getRange(2 + j, 1).setValue(content[j].id);
            ss.getRange(2 + j, 2).setValue(content[j].first_name);
            ss.getRange(2 + j, 3).setValue(content[j].last_name);
            ss.getRange(2 + j, 4).setValue(content[j].display_name);
            ss.getRange(2 + j, 5).setValue(content[j].email);
            ss.getRange(2 + j, 6).setValue(content[j].user_type_id);
            ss.getRange(2 + j, 7).setValue(content[j].role);

        }

       }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide a sanitised example sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the same range of `getRange(2 + j, 1)` is used as the start range every time in the loop. By this, the values are overwritten by new `content`.
- In this modification, the for loop for `content` is removed and put the values at the outside of the for loop. The retrieved `content` is added to the array of `contents` in the 1st for loop. By this, all `content` values (`contents`) can be put to the sheet of `Team` by `setValues`. And also, the process cost can be reduced a little.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var team_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < range1.length; i++) {
  if (range1[i][0] >= behind && range1[i][0] <= ahead) {
    var lastRow = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 1, 1, 8).getValues();
    var dateval = lastRow[0][2]
    var data = {'project_id': lastRow[0][3]};
    var options = {method: 'get',headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + AUTH}};
    var url = tknurlL + Endpoint + data.project_id + '/users?auth=' + AUTH 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var team = JSON.parse(response);
    var content = team.data;
    team_array.push(content);           
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Team');
    const lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < content.length; j++) {
      ss.getRange(2 + j, 1).setValue(content[j].id);
      ss.getRange(2 + j, 2).setValue(content[j].first_name);
      ss.getRange(2 + j, 3).setValue(content[j].last_name);
      ss.getRange(2 + j, 4).setValue(content[j].display_name);
      ss.getRange(2 + j, 5).setValue(content[j].email);
      ss.getRange(2 + j, 6).setValue(content[j].user_type_id);
      ss.getRange(2 + j, 7).setValue(content[j].role);
    }
  }
}
```

To:

```
var contents = [];  // Added
var team_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < range1.length; i++) {
  if (range1[i][0] >= behind && range1[i][0] <= ahead) {
    var lastRow = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 1, 1, 8).getValues();
    var dateval = lastRow[0][2]
    var data = {'project_id': lastRow[0][3]};
    var options = {method: 'get',headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + AUTH}};
    var url = tknurlL + Endpoint + data.project_id + '/users?auth=' + AUTH 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var team = JSON.parse(response);
    var content = team.data;
    team_array.push(content);
    contents = contents.concat(content);  // Added
  }
}
// I added below script.
if (contents.length > 0) {
  var dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Team');
  var values = contents.map(e => ([e.id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.display_name, e.email, e.user_type_id, e.role]));
  dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: @willy Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.